# Android: Skype call not working while both phones recording audio

Tags: android, skype, mediarecorder, audiorecord

I am running into a very unique issue. I am making an android app that records audio using the MediaRecorder class. I set the audio source to MIC. I have 2 phones and I start up the app on each phone and then use one phone to Skype call other. The Skype call rings but neither phone can transmit audio. Skype works fine on both  phones when I turn off my audiorecording app on one phone or both phones. The unique issue only arises when I try to record voice while both the phones have my application running in the background.

Comment: Have you solved the problem?